# How to use before_action with :unless and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an authorization module that I built to authorize user actions. Everything is working great, except now I want to skip the action if the user requesting the page is the current user. The resource is nested below `user` so passes a `:user_id` as part of the params.

From what I've been able to find out, the simplest way to do this is to use a lambda, but it doesn't appear that I have access to the passed params from the before filter.

This is my controller

```
class Certifications::FitnessController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authorize, unless: -> { params[:user_id] == current_user.id }
end
```

The problem is that the `:authorize` before_action is never called so all actions are allowed (I assume because the unless statement is always evaluating to true), but I can't examine what is going on because if I stop execution there, no params seem to be there (which I would think should make it always evaluate to false, not true).

If anyone can tell me either what I'm doing wrong or a better way to implement, I would really appreciate it.

**EDIT:** The code above actually works if you convert the params to an integer to match the current_user.id

```
before_action :authorize, unless: -> { params[:user_id].to_i == current_user.id }
```

Comment: can you define method in controller like `def is_current_user params[:user_id] == current_user.id   end ` in your before action `before_action :authorize, unless: -> is_current_user` something like this

Comment: I was able to inline it in the code above, I just needed to convert the params to an integer to match the type for current_user.id

Comment: ahha, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  before_action do |controller|
    unless params[:user_id].to_i == current_user.id
      controller.authorize 
    end
  end
```

Alternatively you can do so like:-

```
before_action :authorize

def authorize
  unless params[:user_id].to_i == current_user.id
    #do your stuff..
  end
end
```

2nd Alternative

```
before_action :authorize, unless: -> { params[:user_id].to_i == current_user.id }
```

Comment: This works if you call `.to_i` on the params. Actually, the lamda call above works as well if I add that...Thank for putting me on the right track.

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone Well i have added your lamda call answer too :D thank you.

Comment: you have to call `.to_i` as I did in the edit (in both your code and mine). `params[:user_id] returns a string so the comparison is, for example, "1" == 1 which won't allow the current user perform actions on records they own.

Comment: Great answer. Just a useful tidbit: [this](https://reganchan.ca/blog/ordering-of-filters-in-rails-controllers/) shows the order in which callbacks are executed. In my case I had to go to the application_controller since I needed things to run before the callbacks in a specific controller.

Comment: As a Ruby/Rails noob, why in your final example does it have to be `unless: -> { condition }` not just `unless: condition`?